# ismember issue with dates

Tags: matlab, date

I'm having some issues with the function `ismember` of MATLAB. I have two date variables with different lenghts that I would like to compare and find the similarities:

[image: Date1] [image: Date2]

So I used `ismember(Date1,Date2)`, but the logical values that I get are always 0, even if it is the same date.

Do you know how to correct this issue ? Should I use a function other than `ismember`?

Comment: I don't see any dates in common between the two variables you show.

Comment: Also, please show some code that demonstrates how you represent your dates. I cannot reproduce your issue using cell arrays of strings nor using `datetime` objects.

Comment: Hello, so I only put here a small screenshot (Data size is around 317777 rows) to show the kind of data. I checked manually and there are common dates. To answer the second question, everything is in datetime format.

Comment: Please show some code. I cannot reproduce your problem with `datetime` objects. `Date1=datetime({'21/1/2010','4/12/2010'}); Date2=[datetime('24/8/2010'),Date1(1)]; ismember(Date1,Date2)` returns `[1,0]` as expected.

Comment: Most likely you are using `ismember` or interpreting the results wrong. Show a [complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If your claim is right, just have a few dates in `date1` and `date2` with common dates as a test and post them here.

Comment: timeIrr = datetime(num2str(TimeP),'InputFormat','yyyyMMddHH','Format','dd/MM/yyyy'); 
timeT = datetime(Date, 'Format', 'dd/MM/yyyy');   ismember(timeIrr,timeT);

Answer (score 1):

If you get zeros from ismember

```
TimeP = {'01/01/1981','26/01/1981'};
Date =  {'01/01/1981','26/01/1981','20/02/1981','11/02/1981'};
timeIrr = datetime(TimeP,'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy'); 
timeT   = datetime(Date, 'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy'); 
ismember(timeT,timeIrr)
```

Just add

```
dateshift(yourDate,'start','end')
```

In this way:

```
TimeP = {'01/01/1981','26/01/1981'};
Date =  {'01/01/1981','26/01/1981','20/02/1981','11/02/1981'};
timeIrr = datetime(TimeP,'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy'); 
timeT1 = datetime(Date, 'InputFormat','dd/MM/yyyy'); 
timeT = dateshift(timeT1, 'start', 'day'); 
ismember(timeT,timeIrr)
```

Output:

```
ans =
  1×4 logical array
   1   1   0   0
```